# React how to update component

Tags: reactjs

Here is the component:

```
class ProductList extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
    getProducts((err, products) => {
        if(err) return console.log('error: ', err);
        this.setState({products})
    })
}

render() {
    const data = this.state.products;
    return (
        <div>
            <Table dataSource={data}>

                <Column title={'Id'} dataIndex={"_id"} key={'_id'}/>
                <Column title={'Name'} dataIndex={"name"} key={'name'}/>
                <Column title={'Price'} dataIndex={"price"} key={'price'}/>
                <Column title={'Type'} dataIndex={"type"} key={'type'}/>
                <Column title={'Category'} dataIndex={"category"} key={'category'}/>

            </Table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

and I'm getting `Cannot read property 'products' of null` error, I think it's because when `Table` renders the `products` were yet to be added to the state, so how to update the component after state changes?

Comment: You should set an initial state; the component will already be re-rendered when the state changes, that's part of what React does.

Comment: @jonrsharpe man, I forgot to set the initial state, so sorry

Comment: first define the state

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductList extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {products: []};
}


componentWillMount() {
    getProducts((err, products) => {
        if(err) return console.log('error: ', err);
        this.setState({products})
    })
}

render() {
    const data = this.state.products;
    return (
        <div>
            <Table dataSource={data}>

                <Column title={'Id'} dataIndex={"_id"} key={'_id'}/>
                <Column title={'Name'} dataIndex={"name"} key={'name'}/>
                <Column title={'Price'} dataIndex={"price"} key={'price'}/>
                <Column title={'Type'} dataIndex={"type"} key={'type'}/>
                <Column title={'Category'} dataIndex={"category"} key={'category'}/>

            </Table>
        </div>
    );
 } 
 }
```